# Change homepage URL in XML sitemap

Tags: wordpress, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml

I want homepage URL of my site changed from https://backend.migrateworld.com/ to https://backend.migrateworld.com/en in my sitemap XML file only. I'm using ALL in one seo plugin and site is in wordpress. Thanks for help.

https://backend.migrateworld.com/page-sitemap.xml

I tried finding this file in cpanel but not able to find it. This file is generated by ALL in one seo plugin.

Comment: If you use WPML, sitemap will have for each language url. If that some weird redirection you can add it as additional page in sitemap settings and remove the original page from the same settings. https://aioseo.com/docs/how-to-exclude-content-from-your-xml-sitemap/ Also fix your cannonical url since its same page.

Comment: I tried excluding URL from setting but still it is there in sitemap. Looks like settings are not working properly. Is there a way to do it through coding?